# HTML Canvas: Drawn item keeps zooming or panning

Tags: typescript, canvas

I'm not getting any errors, but then when I mouse down and move the mouse the item on the canvas moves in the correct direction but it doesn't stop, it just slides right of the canvas, same when I zoom in or out with the mouse wheel, its zooms but again doesn't stop.

I expect the item on the canvas to stop zooming when I stop moving the mouse wheel, I also expect the item to stop panning when I mouse up after dragging.

CodeSanbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-sdx09

The react component that loads the canvas is

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { Grid } from './grid';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const canvasRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);


  const setGrid = () => {
    const grid = new Grid({w: 800, h: 800});
    if (canvasRef.current) {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      if (ctx) {
        let now = 0;
        const tickLoop = (epoch: number) => {
          const tick = epoch - now;
          now = epoch;
          ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 800, 800);
          grid.update(tick);
          grid.draw(ctx);
          requestAnimationFrame(tickLoop);
        };
        requestAnimationFrame(tickLoop);
      }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setGrid();
  });

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <canvas
        ref={canvasRef}
        width={800}
        height={800}
      ></canvas>

    </React.Fragment>
  );
};

export { App };
```

The imported component called grid...

```
import { InputHandler } from './inputHandler';

export interface WHInterface {
  w: number;
  h: number;
}

export interface ControlInterface {
  view: { x: number; y: number; zoom: number };
  viewPos: { prevX: number | null; prevY: number | null; isDragging: boolean };
}

export interface InputHandlerInterface {
  setZoom(event: WheelEvent): void;
  setPan(event: MouseEvent, mouseDown: boolean): void;
  setMouseDown(event: MouseEvent, mouseDown: boolean): void;
}

class Grid implements InputHandlerInterface {
  canvasSize: WHInterface;
  controls: ControlInterface;

  constructor(canvasSize: WHInterface) {
    this.canvasSize = canvasSize;
    this.controls = {
      view: { x: 0, y: 0, zoom: 1 },
      viewPos: { prevX: null, prevY: null, isDragging: false },
    };
    new InputHandler(this);
  }


  update(tick: number) {
    //
  }

  draw(ctx: CanvasRenderingContext2D) {
    ctx.fillStyle = 'grey';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 800, 800);

    ctx.translate(this.controls.view.x, this.controls.view.y);
    ctx.scale(this.controls.view.zoom, this.controls.view.zoom);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fillRect(20, 20, 20, 20);
  }

  setMouseDown(event: MouseEvent, mouseDown: boolean) {
    const { x, y } = event;
    if (mouseDown) {
    this.controls.viewPos.isDragging = true;
    this.controls.viewPos.prevX = x;
    this.controls.viewPos.prevY = y;
    }
    if (!mouseDown) {
      this.controls.viewPos.isDragging = false;
      this.controls.viewPos.prevX = null;
      this.controls.viewPos.prevY = null;
    }
  }
  setPan(event: MouseEvent, mouseDown: boolean) {
    const { x, y } = event;
    if (mouseDown) {
      const pos = {x, y};
      let dx;
      let dy;
      if (this.controls.viewPos.prevX) dx = x - this.controls.viewPos.prevX;
      if (this.controls.viewPos.prevY) dy = y - this.controls.viewPos.prevY;

      if (this.controls.viewPos.prevX || this.controls.viewPos.prevY) {
        if (dx) this.controls.view.x += dx;
        if (dy )this.controls.view.y += dy;
        this.controls.viewPos.prevX = pos.x;
        this.controls.viewPos.prevY = pos.y;
      }
    }
  }

  setZoom(event: WheelEvent) {
    const {x, y, deltaY} = event;
    const direction = deltaY > 0 ? -1 : 1;
    const factor = 0.0005;
    const zoom = 1 * direction * factor;

    const wx = (x - this.controls.view.x) / (800 * this.controls.view.zoom);
    const wy = (y - this.controls.view.y) / (800 * this.controls.view.zoom);

    this.controls.view.x -= wx * 800 * zoom;
    this.controls.view.y -= wy * 800 * zoom;
    this.controls.view.zoom += zoom;
  }
}

export { Grid };
```

And the input handler

```
import { InputHandlerInterface } from './grid';

class InputHandler {
  mouseDown: boolean;
  constructor(grid: InputHandlerInterface) {
    this.mouseDown = false;

    window.addEventListener(
      'wheel',
      (event: WheelEvent) => {
        grid.setZoom(event);
      },
      false
    );
    window.addEventListener(
      'mousedown',
      (event) => {
        this.mouseDown = true;
        grid.setMouseDown(event, true);
      },
      false
    );
    window.addEventListener(
      'mouseup',
      (event) => {
        this.mouseDown = false;
        grid.setMouseDown(event, false);
      },
      false
    );
    window.addEventListener(
      'mousemove',
      (event) => {
        grid.setPan(event, this.mouseDown);
      },
      false
    );
  }
}

export { InputHandler };
```